# How to use postfix to send emails via/as(?) a signed up user

Tags: email, postfix

This question may be a little vague, bear me with here, I honestly don't know what to even search for to get to the right answer.

I'm playing around with Postfix. It's up and running, I can send emails. Got my TXT records in place, DMARC, even got DKIM and all that good stuff.

I was planning on using Postfix, PHP and a bunch of other stuff to make a simple API to send emails. Users could use that API to send emails to other users as themselves.

So the process would be user A(a@somesite.com) uses the API to send an email to user B(b@othersite.com). So far so good.

Only one small problem in my full proof plan. Gmail, for example, will completely block my email IF the `From` address is not the registered domain name. And rightfully so.

When I use services like mailchip I get a nice

```
from:   Name <foo@bar.com> via mailchimp.com
```

And this is where I'm stuck.

How I go about having the `via` when using my own email server?

I realize this question is really vague and may have a lot of answers. Just please point me in the right direction here, even an article of some sort will get me going.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to do it just with `postfix`, but if you take a look at how `mailman` and `sympa` handle DMARC, that is at least a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *sendmail* to do that. Its as simple as using any email address you wish as the sender.
One example is to add the information to a file named *usefakeaddress*:

```
From: faker@sender.fake
To: receiver@sucker.com
Subject: all of your base 

are belong to us
```

then call sendmail with:

```
cat usefakeaddress | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: That's a very good way to get myself blacklisted.

Comment: Maybe use something other than Gmail?